# What can be the cause that websphere is way slower than Tomcat

Tags: java, performance, tomcat, websphere

Same POJO code using very basic JDK math api, nothing related to persistence layer, just POJO, however the iteration may go for millions rounds, so total time difference from Websphere to Tomcat could be 10:1. The code is something like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<200000;i++){
    logger.info("calculate result 1");
    int result_int1 = new Double(param1_double_left / param1_double_right).intValue();
    logger.info("calculate result 2");
    int result_int2 = new Double(param2_double_left / param2_double_right).intValue();
    logger.info("calculate result 3");
    int result_int3 = new Double(param3_double_left / param3_double_right).intValue();
    logger.info("calculate result 4");
    int result_int4 = new Double(param4_double_left / param4_double_right).intValue();
    logger.info("calculate result 5");
    int result_int5 = new Double(param5_double_left / param5_double_right).intValue();
    //... more calculation with java math like above
}
```

From log4j log from tomcat, it is pretty fast, so the time stamp is like

```
2016-12-05 17:53:31,200 INFO .... <-200
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:53:31,201 INFO .... <-201
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:53:31,202 INFO .... <-202
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:53:31,203 INFO .... <-203
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:53:31,204 INFO .... <-204
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
```

From log4j log from websphere, the the timestamp increase with more time for each surge

```
2016-12-05 17:55:47,197 INFO .... <-197
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:55:47,212 INFO .... <-212
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:55:47,239 INFO .... <-239
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:55:47,251 INFO .... <-251
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
2016-12-05 17:55:47,277 INFO .... <-277
.... another 10 - 20 lines with same timestamp
```

So just wondering what could be the factor regarding the slowness in websphere. GC? or other JVM tuning?

Comment: are you using the same JDK in each case?  How are you measuring time?  Are you precisely measuring the for loop or is server startup time getting pulled in?

Comment: @aguibert yes same JDK (JDK7). Tomcat 6 vs Websphere 8.5. I use log4j and I can see in log from websphere. I have updated the question hopefully can clear the situation a little bit. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are measuring the performance of log4j more than the performance of the jdk math API by printing to logs after every computation. If you want to do it right, take a `System.currentTimeInMillis()` once at the start and once at the end and print the difference.

Second, when a multithreaded application runs when there are more threads than CPU cores (which is the case with websphere) the threads will need to be scheduled and take turns running, which is why you see the websphere messages logged in batches.

Finally, using the speed of a jdk API to measure performance of application servers doesn't really make any sense. A more accurate thing to do would be measuring server start time or requests/second (which tomcat will almost surely win out in small scale testing because it's lightweight).  It's like comparing a motorcycle to a semi truck, they have different strengths in performance.

A more interesting comparison would be tomcat vs. websphere liberty, which is the newer more lightweight version of websphere traditional.

Comment: Thanks for the nice feedback. Actually I am not evaluating app server performance, just trying to find a way to make the same code working as fast in WAS as in Tomcat. Regarding the second point, I install WAS on 8 core cpu with 16g memory, with single application deployed and just a single thread running when above POJO math is processing... still see the "batch" difference in timestamp. yes I do use Log4J is that the possible reason? I know websphere by nature not very friendly with Log4j instead of common logging?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Log4j performance on WAS, but since it's simply third-party software that plugs into the product I don't see why it would be slower on WAS compared to using Log4j with any other piece of software. In any case, what I suggested in the first paragraph should still be a valid way to measure things.